# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I've been trying to fetch all the rows where the user id is. then I got this error. Please help me.

CONTROLLER:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $applications = application::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();

        if (empty($applications)) {
            $applications = "0";
            return view('user.application.index',compact('applications'));
        }
        else{
        return view('user.application.index',compact('applications'));
        }
    }
```

blade file

```
 @foreach ($applications as $application)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $loop->index +1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ $application->surname }}, {{ $application->firstname }} {{ $application->middlename }}</td>
    @if ($application->status == 1)
    <td><p style="color:green;">APPROVED</p></td>
    @elseif ($application->status == 0)
    <td><p style="color:rgb(243, 180, 8);">PENDING</p></td>
    @else
    <td><p style="color:RED;">DISAPPROVED</p></td>
    @endif
    <td><a href = "{{ route('user.application.show', $application->id)}}"><img src = {{ asset('assets/img/eye.ico') }}/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$applications='0'` with `$applications=[]` and see if it works ;)